# How far away were galaxies when they emitted the light we now see?

Tags: astronomy

If we had a way to measure the apparent distance to 13billion light year galaxies (parallax or something) what would it be? The light left the source 13 billion years ago, so it would appear much closer.
I can't find an answer and I'm hoping you know.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "apparent distance" here? Parallax is usually measured against a "distant" background (and even difficult to detect for close-by stars!), but a galaxy at the edge of the observable universe doesn't *have* a more distant background.

Comment: the problem is the expansion(accelerating) of the universe, if light that was emitted from a source 13billion years ago, that source is now much farther then 13 billion light years away. The universe is 13billion years old, but the radius of the observable universe is much bigger then that.